# How handle atomic changes to lock-free data structures?

Tags: rust, concurrency

Code below was desired to handle size of the map and make kind of it's rotation, based on total size.
The problem is in concurrent calls. I can't avoid writing way more data than I expected. I want to have advantages of lock-free backed data-store, but don't know what kind of pattern can help me.

```
struct Store {
    map: DashMap<String, Vec<u8>>,
    size: RwLock<usize>,
}
impl Store {
    pub fn put(&self, key: String, buf: Vec<u8>) {
        let clean_needed = {
            let size = self.size.read().unwrap();
            println!("Size {}", *size);
            *size  >= 50000usize
        };
        let buff_size = buf.len();
        if clean_needed {
            let mut size = self.size.write().unwrap();
            *size = 0;
            self.map.clear();
            println!("Store cleaned");
        } else {
            let mut size = self.size.write().unwrap();
            *size += buff_size;
            self.map.entry(key).and_modify(|e| e.extend(buf)).or_insert(Vec::new());
            println!("Buff added: {}", buff_size);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From your question, it's not clear what the problem is. Does the code work as expected? If not, how does the observed behavior differ from what you expect?

Comment: yes, it not works as expected. while concurrent calls buffer can exceed max size even twice than expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a race condition because you lock `size` multiple times. Annotating your code to explain:

```rust
        let clean_needed = {
            // Multiple threads can take a read lock at the same time
            let size = self.size.read().unwrap();
            println!("Size {}", *size);
            // If the size was less than 50000,
            // All would conclude `clean_needed = false`
            *size  >= 50000usize
        };
        let buff_size = buf.len();
        if clean_needed {
            let mut size = self.size.write().unwrap();
            *size = 0;
            self.map.clear();
            println!("Store cleaned");
        } else {
            // Then they will each sequentially take a write lock
            let mut size = self.size.write().unwrap();
            // And increment the size
            *size += buff_size;
            // And push their data in
            self.map.entry(key).and_modify(|e| e.extend(buf)).or_insert(Vec::new());
            // Causing the size to overflow the limit
            println!("Buff added: {}", buff_size);
        }
```

The solution is to hold the write lock for the whole routine:

```rust
struct Store {
    map: DashMap<String, Vec<u8>>,
    size: RwLock<usize>,
}
impl Store {
    pub fn put(&self, key: String, mut buf: Vec<u8>) {
        let mut size = self.size.write().unwrap();

        let clean_needed = {
            println!("Size {}", *size);
            *size >= 50000usize
        };
        let buff_size = buf.len();
        if clean_needed {
            self.map.clear();
            *size = 0;
            println!("Store cleaned");
        } else {
            self.map
                .entry(key)
                .and_modify(|e| e.append(&mut buf))
                .or_insert(buf);
            *size += buff_size;
            println!("Buff added: {}", buff_size);
        }
    }
}
```

I also fixed your `.and_modify(...).or_insert(...)` so it uses [`Vec::append`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.append) if there is an occupied entry, and just inserts `buf` directly if the entry was vacant.

[playground](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b#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)

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, this was one of the solutions that i tried. But I wanted somehow avoid write lock on the hole function with RwLock or Atomics :)

So, in case of write lock, we can also use Mutex instead of RwLock.

Comment: Why avoid the write lock on the whole function? You end up taking a write lock in the end anyways, and checking the size after locking is a practically free operation compared to taking a read lock and a write lock later.

Comment: Yeah, I know. It was mostly for education purposes. Like maybe there are some another patterns in such things that I'm not so familiar with. Thank you for you response!